# Cordova Plugins Working on android 4.2.2 and not working on 4.4.2 , above

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

App Installed Successfully but Cordova Plugins Working on android 4.2.2 and not working on 4.4.2 , above

on android 4.2.2 everything is ok and all plugins working ,, when i use the app on android 4.4.2 or later the app working but no plugin work ...
all plugins Not Working on 4.4.2 and above .. Can anyone help me plz

my code

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>        
        <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
            checkConnection();
        }
        //------
        function checkConnection() {
            var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
            if(networkState==Connection.NONE){
                document.getElementById("main-content").innerHTML="<div style='text-align:center;'><img src='img/internet.png' style='max-width:100%;' /></div>";
            }
        
        }
        
        //------
         function teachers(){
            var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://ataksa.com/?p=serv4', '_self', 'location=no');
        }
        //------
        function news(){
            var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://ataksa.com/?p=serv6', '_self', 'location=no');
        }
        //------
        function jobs(){
            var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://ataksa.com/?p=serv7', '_self', 'location=no');
        }
        //------
        function estb(){
            var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://ataksa.com/?p=serv8', '_self', 'location=no');
        }
        //------
        function pro(){
            var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://ataksa.com/?p=serv9', '_self', 'location=no');
        }
        //------
       function internal(){
            var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://ataksa.com/?p=serv10', '_self', 'location=no');
        }
        //------
        function external(){
            var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://ataksa.com/?p=serv11', '_self', 'location=no');
        }
        //------
        function online(){
            var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://ataksa.com/?p=serv12', '_self', 'location=no');
        }
        //------
        
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using cordova.InAppBrowser.open() that that cordova.InAppBrowser.open() did not work (Android 5/6).

After including the plug-in, instead us the standard window.open(url,system)

```
plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" 
window.open(URL, '_system');
```